# Double variable for loops (tax calculator)

Tags: python, loops

trying to create a tax calculator for logic practice:

```
import sys

marital = sys.argv[1]
salary = sys.argv[2]

totalTaxes = 0

if marital == "single":

    tiers = [415050,413350,190150,91150,37650,9275]
    taxrates = [.35,.33,.28,.25,.15,.10]
    if salary > tiers[i]:
        for i, j in tiers, taxrates:
            for n in range(i-(i+1)):
                while n > tiers[i]:
                    totalTaxes += (n * .35)
```

This makes sense to me when I'm looking at it but that for loop is causing an error.  I've seen double-variable for loops before but can't remember how to do them.  Do I use `enumerate` or `itertools` in some way?

Also, I'm open to any suggestions on how to reduce the number of nesting loops I have here.  I'm sure that's doable.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

For clarity, the `for n in range(i,i-(i+1)):` portion is to calculate that bracket of tax for that first interval.  Essentially I'm calculating that interval's tax rate for each dollar in the interval and adding that to totalTaxes.  Not very efficient but it's all I have.

By the way error is `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: You're using `tiers[i]` before you set `i`.

Comment: `for a,b in zip(iterable_a, iterable_b)`?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of the for loop is you misused it. `For i in a_list` will iterate each item in `a_list` and populate the item value to i (not the index). Also if you want to combine two lists together in the for loop, you should use `zip`.

```
import sys

marital = sys.argv[1]
salary = sys.argv[2]

totalTaxes = 0

if marital == "single":

    tiers = [415050,413350,190150,91150,37650,9275]
    taxrates = [.35,.33,.28,.25,.15,.10]
    for tier, taxrate in zip(tiers, taxrates):
        ...
```

I'm not sure what you are doing inside of the for loop. `range(i-(i+1))` is identical to `range(-1)` which means the program will never run the while loop. What your logic is?

Comment: Okay, great.  That got rid of the error.  I'm getting 0 as the answer now.